# Passing data between mongoose promises?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Say I have two schemas namely **Vehicles** and **Users** and a function by the name **buyVehicle** which takes a **vehicleId** from the request body and adds the vehicle info obtained by querying Vehicles schema using the vehicleId into the logged-in user document.

For ex - buyVehicle() with vehicleId 00ford125 will add all the information related for that particular vehicle into the logged-in user document.

Code:

```
function buyVehicle(req, res) {
    Vehicles.findOne({'vehicleId' : req.body.vehicleId}).exec()
    .then(function(vehicle) {
        if(vehicle) {
            return User.findOne({'_id': req.user._id}).exec();
        }
    })
    .then(function(user) {
        if(user) {
            // here I need to vehicle object which was queried above
            user.save();
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

In the second promise (where I've put a comment), I need the vehicle object which was queried above so I can pull the info and add it to the user object.

So, in simple terms, How do I pass around data between Mongoose promises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many many different ways with promises, but perhaps the easiest is to just save the value in the upper scope, like so...

```
function buyVehicle(req, res) {
    let vehicle; // 1. Declare the variable in the function scope

    Vehicles.findOne({'vehicleId' : req.body.vehicleId}).exec()
    .then(function(foundVehicle) {
        if(foundVehicle) {
            vehicle = foundVehicle; // 2. Assign it here...

            return User.findOne({'_id': req.user._id}).exec();
        }
    })
    .then(function(user) {
        if(user) {
            // 3. Call it here
            console.log(vehicle);
            user.save();
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something like that too. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, if this answered your question could you please mark it as the answer? This helps people who search for it in the future find it easier.